# Gem's Rake tasks to use current location

Tags: file, rake, task

In a [gem](https://github.com/ZenCocoon/rspec-subject-extensions) I use [Appraisal](https://github.com/thoughtbot/appraisal) to test against different gem dependencies.

The problem I face is that [Appraisal](https://github.com/thoughtbot/appraisal) try to run the command :

`BUNDLE_GEMFILE=gemfiles/3.0.gemfile bundle exec /Users/seb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/bin/rake spec cucumber`

This cause an issue with the cucumber test as aruba's file are located in a subdirectory `tmp/aruba`

A solution would be to get [Appraisal](https://github.com/thoughtbot/appraisal) to use absolute path to locate the gemfiles and therefore run something like follow instead:

`BUNDLE_GEMFILE=/Users/seb/Work/GitHub/rspec-subject-extensions/gemfiles/3.0.gemfile bundle exec /Users/seb/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/bin/rake spec cucumber`

Question is, **how to get [Appraisal](https://github.com/thoughtbot/appraisal) rake tasks to know the current location ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dir.pwd` seems to do just that. Thanks to [croaky](https://github.com/croaky) for the tip.